# Raspberry pi 64 bit Os showing Unable to locate package libjasper-dev. how to fix this?

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, operating-system, arm

I am using a raspberry pi 4.
And I installed a 64-bit (not 32-bit) Raspberry Pi OS.
When I tried to install libjasper-dev using the command
'sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev' as a part of OpenCV.
It is showing "Unable to locate package libjasper-dev".
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, or how to compile OpenCV correctly on a Rasbian 64Bit ?

For example, this (among other errors) happens when installing the image raspios_lite_arm64-2021-11-08 on an 8GB Raspi4 and trying to follow the instructions on https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/synchronized-stereo-camera-hat/opencv-and-depth-map-on-arducam-stereo-camera-hat-tutorial/:

```
pi@roverpi:~ $ sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libatlas-base-dev libjasper-dev libqtgui4 libqt4-test
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libhdf5-dev' instead of 'libhdf5-serial-dev'
Package libqtgui4 is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libjasper-dev
E: Package 'libqtgui4' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-test
```

Anyone know how to fix this

Comment: No idea why it looked unclear to someone. I've run into the same problem. The above description of the problem is OK.

Comment: I also think this should be reopened. I also have the libjasper-dev problem and still haven't found any solution (the libqt issue I could solve by substituting the libqt5 package names).

Comment: I also think this should be re-opened.  I have exactly the same issue, a Pi 4B, running Pi version 3.9.2.  Am following the youtube instructions from the Sam Westby video titled "How to install OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi" (dated Feb 5, 2022).    However, I ran the sequence of library installs last night and it worked ok on the 32-bit version of Pi OS (Bullseye), however today I am trying it on the 64-bit version and it is failing exactly as described above.